# Where can I find a camera holster or case that stays on the camera?

Tags: canon-550d, equipment-protection, camera-cases

25 years ago my Minolta camera came with a standard case in two parts. the one part wrapped around the body and never left the camera unless you changed the film. It held on with it's snug shape and secured by wrapping two little faux leather strips around the strap links on the sides of the camera. Meanwhile the part that covered the top and lens just snapped on. When you wanted to take a picture you'd unsnap instantly and flip the cover off the lens and it would hang off the body cover below and you could operate all the functions. There was even a hole for the tripod so to this day I still have that case on the old camera.

But I can't find anything like this for the T2i I just ordered? The nearest thing seems to be neoprene cases but I think you still have to pull the whole camera out? I know there is more buttons and the screen on the back, but it would seam easy enough to still create a similar case?

The nearest thing I found looks to be the green case for this Special Edition Jackie Chan T2i here: http://news.mydrivers.com/1/162/162391.htm

Or will some of the ones that I think are simply covers do the same thing as my old Minolta cover?

Comment: You could go with an underwater housing :P

Comment: The term you were looking for is an **ever-ready** case, and there's a reason why we used to call them **never-ready** cases. I liked them on rangefinder cameras (like the leaf-shutter Minolta) where you had to half-disassemble the camera anyway to change the film, but I remember throwing out the one I got with my X-700 within a couple of weeks. You had to take the case off far too often, and the knurled screw really didn't give enough contact with a tripod for anything but level landscape-oriented camera positions.

Comment: I didn't use a tripod enough for it to be a problem and I don't remember any issues with flipping the top half off. I do remember it being really easy and handy, and no ordeal with a separate case hanging around your neck. It didn't have the feel of taking a picture with no case, but when one the go it was fine. It does seem these cases have fallen out of favor with newer cameras though.

Comment: I just loved this case for my fathers EXA I. Never had any problems with the tripod - but off course you had to take it off for changing the film. I'd really like to have something for my D90 too.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect those went out of fashion when the standard kit lens went from a compact 50mm to a relatively bulky 18-55mm zoom. Additionally, modern cameras expect one to access whole bunch of controls (including a big rear LCD).

I did find this, though: [BodyGuard Clear Back](http://www.lenscoat.com/bodyguard-clear-backsuptmsup-p-1036.html). It's not exactly the same but seems to fill some of the same function. There's also a product called "[Camera Armor](http://www.cameraarmor.com/)", although that seems more geared at extra protection than really replacing a case/bag.

And of course, there's always [this](http://cloakbags.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Searching the term "leather" and also "ever ready" (as suggested) has led me to find a few possible cases. The most plausible actually is from canon and listed as an accessory for the T2i. It is very highly reviewed, but it's expensive. I don't think it works quite like the old minolta case, but essentially it can be attached and not totally separate from the camera strap. Funny though  I can't find a single photo of one with a camera in it, or even open to see what the 'back' looks like! [http://www.amazon.com/Canon-2748B002-EH19-L-Semi-Hard/dp/B00130VLZ4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00130VLZ4)

And here are a couple more that look promising on ebay, but I've no idea if they are really workable, so purchasing would be a gamble: 
http://cgi.ebay.com/Leather-Camera-Case-Bag-EOS-550D-Rebel-T2i-case-/120647586855?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c17281427 
http://cgi.ebay.com/Leather-Case-Bag-Canon-Rebel-T2i-T1i-XSi-18-55mm-BK-/230576474757?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35af6dca85

Thanks for all the comments and other product suggestions

Comment: Like you, I miss the leather ever-ready case. If you buy one please give us some feedback about how well it works.

Comment: The Canon case looks like something you remove altogether to take a picture (although it would stay on the camera strap). There appears to be a big velcro flap on the right-hand side of the back and a hinge on the left (looking from the camera back), so you'd open the back of the case and withdraw the camera to shoot. It still leaves you with a single strap to manage, but it sounds like it would be more awkward than the ever-ready we remember from the Olde Days. I'd try to see one in person before buying.

Comment: thanks Stan. Good idea. That is how I imagined it too. I just got the camera today and wow does it have a different feel compared to my Minolta from decades ago! At first it felt kind of plastic and cheap, but it has grown on me in the first hours and I suspect the initial reaction won't be lasting.

Answer (score 1):

Even if not exactly the same, the [Op/Tech Soft Pouch](http://optechusa.com/soft-pouch-digital-d-series.html) are the closest case that I know.
I have a neoprene strap from them and it's pretty good quality.

I also had a [Shutter M from Kata](http://www.kata-bags.com/productFRM2HS.asp?p_Id=335&Version=Photo) but my camera body doesn't fit in it anymore!
Anyway, good quality also, as always from Kata but I find it less convenient that the Soft pouch as the camera is not attached to it.

Comment: thansk for the links!

Answer (score 1):

And hang below your camera acting as a nice wind catcher, ruining your steady hand :)

I found them to be incredibly cumbersome and a pain in the backside personally and never used them :) I think the answer will be either fashion or the 'standard zoom' kit lens replacing the 50mm as said above.

If you did have one, I think that it wouldn't be secure enough given the cut outs for controls on the back.

Comment: I did hang below but I never remember it being a problem. Plus I could unsnap that part if needed. I remember spending a day sightseeing in Paris with my friends and getting food, shopping, etc, and being able to whip it open for a picture, and quickly cover it leaving it around my neck with no worry. I have found a few linked in my own answer. But it's hard to tell if theses will indeed be as easy as I remember. And like you said, with the cut out of the controls and screen perhaps it will be less than ideal. I'd add though that the actual Canon version seems very well liked if expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in this type of case as well.  Lowe makes a similar one (Quick Case) that is 'quick access', although the camera comes completely out of it; but the mechanism of access is similar to the ever-ready.  I haven't tried it but it looks interesting.

http://www.lowepro.com/quickcase